# Saving vector-like (one dimensional) list in python

Tags: python, fortran

i put more details in the original post.

i know the following generates an array-like list.

** in the following, OldDisplace has the same size of PyDisplace

```
#
R_D = {}
keys = PyDisplace.keys()
keys.sort()
for val in keys:
    DX = PyDisplace[val][0] - OldDisplace[val][0]
    DY = PyDisplace[val][1] - OldDisplace[val][1]
    DZ = PyDisplace[val][2] - OldDisplace[val][2]
    R_D[val] = [DX, DY, DZ]
```

Clearly, I am new to Python.

My understanding is that above will generate a table or array, R_D, 
that is the size of 3 by *(size of keys()) ....

Could someone help me to get vector-like list R_D (one-dimensional list) instead ?

so that i can retrieve R_D in the following ways.

```
for val in keys:
   DX = R_D(3*(val-1)+1)
   DY = R_D(3*(val-1)+2) 
   DZ = R_D(3*(val-1)+3)
```

thanks in advance....

Comment: I don't know Fortran, so I can't tell from your example... what exactly will each element of the desired "one-dimensional" list look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what it is you're trying to do :)

It looks like you're generating 3 values at a time and want to append them to the list at each iteration. Am I right?

You can do this very easily with the [**list.extend**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) method. Assuming PyDisplace looks like the code below. I'm guessing PyDisplace is a dictionary containing a list of 3 elements pr key, so I've used some bogus data to show the idea. Please update your question if I'm way off :)

```
PyDisplace = {
    1: [10, 20, 30],
    2: [40, 50, 60],
    3: [70, 80, 90],
}
OldDisplace = {
    1: [1, 2, 3],
    2: [4, 5, 6],
    3: [7, 8, 9],
}

R_D = []  # or 'list()' if you will
keys = PyDisplace.keys()
keys.sort()
for val in keys:
    DX = PyDisplace[val][0] - OldDisplace[val][0]
    DY = PyDisplace[val][2] - OldDisplace[val][3]
    DZ = PyDisplace[val][2] - OldDisplace[val][2]

    # at each iteration, R_D will be extended with 
    # three new elements: DX, DY, DZ
    R_D.extend([DX, DY, DZ])

print R_D



**Output**

In [71]: print R_D
-------> print(R_D)
[9, 18, 27, 36, 45, 54, 63, 72, 81]
```

**So how does this differ from what you're doing?**

Well for one, R_D is a list() instead of a dict(). Lists in python are usually 1-dimensional so it would seem a better fit for your problem here. Also, I'm extending the list with another list at every iteration.

Another way to traverse a dictionary is to use the **dict.iteritems** method. That way you can iterate over the key-value pairs like so:

```
for k,v in PyDisplace.iteritems(): 
    print "key: %s, value: %s" % (k, v)

**Output:**

key: 1, value: [10, 20, 30]
key: 2, value: [40, 50, 60]
key: 3, value: [70, 80, 90]
```

**EDIT:**

> thanks. it seems like the first one is well suited for me at this
>   point. again i am new to Python. eventually i will learn a lot and in
>   that sense the second method is quite not easy to get. which means i
>   need to a lot about Python. i will stdu the key words you mention like
>   "dict.iteritems", etc....thanks again. – user1678622 2 hours ago

Well what **dict.iteritems()** does, is somewhat the same as **dict.keys()** does, which you already know how to iterate over. Let's consider a simpler example, **dict.items()**
dict.items() returns a complete list of 2-tuples of all the key-value pairs in the dictionary, the same way **dict.keys()** return a finite list of keys. You can iterate over it like this:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    print "key: %s\nvalue: %s" % (key, value)
```

The difference is, **dict.iteritems()** returns an [iterable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable) object which you can... iterate through. To the for loop it's the same, but under the hood, the list is returned one item at a time, instead of built in one step which may be slow for big dictionaries for instance. I hope that cleared up some of the fuzz :)?

Comment: thanks. it seems like the first one is well suited for me at this point. again i am new to Python. eventually i will learn a lot and in that sense the second method is quite not easy to get. which means i need to a lot about Python. i will stdu the key words you mention like "dict.iteritems", etc....thanks again.

Comment: @user1678622 I've edited the post to hopefully clarify the iteritems() call for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach: the original code in the question defines R_D as a dictionary. It will work
if you fix the second part to:

```
for val in keys:
  DX = R_D[val][0]
  DY = R_D[val][1]
  DZ = R_D[val][2]
```

If you actually want to do arithmetic on array indices then you need to define R_D as a list,
but python dictionaries are a powerful tool worth learning..

even better ..

```
for val in keys:
  DX,DY,DZ = R_D[val]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes at this point i need to do some arithmetic on indices. but, I will study "dictionary" to get to know better. thanks again.